# Find $S_{PCD} $ given $S_{ABCD},S_{ABP},S_{BPC}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> In the following figure,$ABCD$ is a paralleogram  in which point $P$ lies in triangle $ABD$ and the areas of $ABCD,ABP,BPC$ are known to be $s_1,s_2,s_3$ respectively. Find $S_{PCD}$

I think the number of unknowns in this problem is more than the number of equations that can be formed!!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_{ABP}+S_{PCD}=\frac{1}{2}PE\cdot AB+\frac{1}{2}PF\cdot CD=\frac{1}{2}(PE+PF)\cdot AB=\frac{1}{2}EF\cdot AB=\frac{1}{2}S_{ABCD}$

Comment: So what is the usage of $S_{BPC}$?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi  $S_{BPC}$ is not used or needed, unless you want to determine $S_{APD}$ too.